# Reading data from firebase database using cloud functions without relying on events

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have researched and only found examples of listeners such as `onWrite()` for instances of accessing data from the database, but these depend on events.
How can I use the functions to read a snapshot from the database only at the time I need it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use HTTPS trigger

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: @alexkucksdorf that's not a duplicate, this question would be useful for people, who don't know that firebase has such feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTPS trigger as described in here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Also, check this official sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server

```
exports.unguessableFunctionName = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return doSomething().then(res => {
    res.status(200).send(res);
  });
});
```

Just make sure, that this endpoint won't be a security issue

Also, you can attach `onWrite` event on protected (read/write == false) database node, so only you can trigger it from console